# Every night a MYSQL crash (Cloud Server, 8 CPU and 24 GB RAM)

Tags: php, mysql

Hello my dear programming friends.

I am a simple man with little knowledge in server/web hosting.

However, currently I have a problem with my hosting.

Every night (!) at 0:02 -> 0:03 sharp our Apache logs are full of error messages. It is always only at night. During the whole day there are no new error messages.

Here are the error messages in the picture.
https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-ff5278-1620029398.png.html
These same error messages are there every night at almost the same time, every day.

And here our current MySQL settings:
https://www.bilder-upload.eu/bild-333309-1620029488.png.html

Do you have any idea what this could be because of and which setting maybe should be changed?

We use a managed cloud server hosting with dedicated resources.
It has 8 CPU and 24 GB RAM.

Thanks a lot for your time and help,

Kind regards

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: It has nothing to do with CPUs or RAM. 2006 error means closed connection due to timeout.

Comment: Okay , thank you very much! So Timeout!  :-) 
Is it "innodb_lock_wait_timeout" which is currently set to 10 Seconds or is it "timeouts" which is currently sitting at 120 Seconds? what and about how much should i change?

Comment: Is it always the same query running? Is there a CRON job scheduled at this time? Is it your own code that is running and causing errors or from a library?

Comment: I don't know what you have to change. Check which queries run between 0:00 and 0:05, it'd be CRON tasks and debug them.

Comment: There is no Cron Job running at this time....

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to your MySQL server cutting the connection due to a timeout.

Try increasing your `wait_timeout` to twice or triple its current value. But you should most certainly investigate the request running at this time.

EDIT: By default `wait_timeout` is set to `28800` seconds *(which is about 8h)*, so if increasing the timeout does nothing, try looking at your `max_allowed_packet` *(which is currently 1024Mb)* and increasing it. It may be that the request your doing every night is exceeding the current maximum packet size.

Comment: What is the maximum value i should set max_allowed_packet and timeout? and is it "innodb_lock_wait_timeout" which is currently set to 10 Seconds or is it "timeouts" which is currently sitting at 120 Seconds? (see picture with settings in og post)

Comment: Well I don't really know, what `timeouts` mean in your config panel but it does not look like `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` is at fault, otherwise you would have a different error message. What does the request you run every night does?

Comment: I dont run anything at night, there is no cron job....nothing. But all the search bots come at night....maybe thats the reason?

Comment: Are you aware of any backup scripts being run at night by the host provider? Maybe that's just them restarting servers, should maybe ask them.

Comment: @Fischwaage well if the search bots come at night and that's the only thing happening it's most likely due to that, maybe it's making a request that causing MySQL to timeout.